# How can I perform a healthcheck on a running Postgres container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

When I used MySQL, I relied on this healthcheck:

```yaml
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
```

What healthcheck command can I use once I switch to PostgreSQL?

I discovered Postgres has a CLI tool called [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) (similar to `mysqlsh`). However it seems I need to feed it a username no matter what. I don't want to hard-code it in that string array, and I strongly believe it doesn't support dynamic placeholders

The [official image's](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) description doesn't mention healthchecks

Comment: You can provide credentials to psql via [environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) or via [a `.pgpass` file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html). There is also a [`pg_isready` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-isready.html) that may do what you want.